# Need suggestion to implement OkHttp connection

Tags: kotlin, okhttp, httpurlconnection, square, httpconnection

I am switching from HTTPURLConnection to OkHttpConnection in my service (Kotlin).

I have implemented below code for GET and POST request function with OKHttp connections. This is great and useful, about 50% latency reduction compared to calling HTTPUrlConnection. I can achieve this, only if I make few requests at a time.

If I make a lot of GET request in period of time (like 10K+), the performance seems to be average. Any suggestions ? Am I need to configure any params to achieve better ?

```
private fun okhttpioConnection(): String {

    log.info("Initializing OKHttp-ioConnection")
    client = OkHttpClient()
    client.setConnectTimeout(600000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    client.setReadTimeout(600000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    client.connectionPool = ConnectionPool(100, 100000)
    client.retryOnConnectionFailure = true

    var request = createRequest(restParams) // GET or POST
    var response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    var responseCodeString = response.code().toString()
    return response.body()!!.string()

}
fun createRequest(restParams: RestParams): Request {
    if (restParams.method == "POST") {
      return Request.Builder()
        .post(RequestBody.create(
          MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), restParams.body.toString()))
        .header("Authorization", "xxxxxx")
        .addHeader("Content-Length",restParams.body.length.toString())
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/json")
        .url(restParams.url)
        .build()
    } else {
    return Request.Builder()
      .header("Authorization", "xxxxxxx")
      .addHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/json")
      .url(restParams.url).get()
      .build()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp doesn't impose a maximum number of connections, any limit will come from the code that is calling okhttp, and I don't think you can do anything to improve the performance further (from the point of view of okhttp). To know for sure you need to share more information such as req/s, latency, number of threads, etc. you are getting now.

Some of the things for you to check, as there are many potential issues:

- Check if your code runs in an Executor that has has a fixed size (this will limit the request/s).
- Check that you are not maxing out your CPU, memory, etc.
- That the server you are hitting is not maxing out on any resources (concurrent threads, CPU, connections, etc) or rate limiting the calls.
- That the process is not maxing the number of allowed TCP sockets open.

These are some of the things that come to my mind, but probably there are many more.